# Why Editing an Answer must needs 6 characters?

Tags: support, editing, answers

I've seen that Editing an answer must be 6 characters expected.Why this rule. From my view,May be some Edits needs 2 or 3 characters only but that is more important for that answer especially that edit may be on `code`,so in this scenario, stopping the edit with restricting in the case of `must be altleast 6 characters can be avoid`.

Comment: May be something reputation based I'm not sure, but I don't believe there are any restrictions on editing an answer, just on adding a new answer or comment.

Comment: That restriction will be removed after you reach 1000 reputation and you get the [edit privilege](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). (On non-beta [SE] sites, you need 2k reputation, not 1k)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is because up to a point of reputation you get reputation for edits. So adding this check should limit people from spam editing to simply to get the reputation. It should help make sure that edits are actually required.